# How to Properly Close Realm Outside of An Activity/Fragment

Tags: android, realm

I am using the code block below to add a Customer object to Realm, the objects are added successfully. However, I am trying to provide feedback via Toast message when the item insertion completes or fails.

```
@Override
public void addCustomer(final Customer customer) {
    Realm insertRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    insertRealm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm backgroundRealm) {
            long id = customerPrimaryKey.incrementAndGet();
            customer.setId(id);
            backgroundRealm.copyToRealm(customer);
        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Customer Added");
        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable error) {
            Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());
        }
    });
    insertRealm.close();

}
```

The above code block inserts the object successfully, however, the success and error callbacks are not reached because I closed the Realm that was used to start it. If I do not close the Realm, then the onError and onSuccess callbacks are reached, however, the app will crash because the Realm is leaked.

I tried to update the code to close the Realm inside the callbacks like this but it still crashed.

```
public void addCustomer(final Customer customer) {
    Realm insertRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    insertRealm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm backgroundRealm) {
            long id = customerPrimaryKey.incrementAndGet();
            customer.setId(id);
            backgroundRealm.copyToRealm(customer);
        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Customer Added");
            insertRealm.close();
        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable error) {
            Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());
            insertRealm.close();
        }
    });        

}
```

SO my question is, is there are way to close Realm outside of the Activity/Fragment LifeCycle? Can I keep a global singleton of Realm and inject into the classes that use it?

Updated - Added StackTrack

```
11-13 06:59:07.545 2249-2257/com.google.android.gms W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/metrics.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
11-13 06:59:07.549 2249-2257/com.google.android.gms W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/help_responses.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
11-13 06:59:07.557 2249-2257/com.google.android.gms W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/auto_complete_suggestions.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
```

Comment: What is the crash stack trace

Comment: I have added the stack trace, it is funny that it is reporting the leaked database as SQLite when I am using Realm. I have wrapped the realm.close statements with a try/catch and now atleast the app is not crashing.

Comment: Those leaks belong to the Google GMS, it doesn't have anything to do with realm or so I would think https://www.android.com/gms/

Answer (score 0):

Closing Realm in the onSuccess and onError callbacks works, the issue I was wrestling with is an existing SQLiteOpenHelper class that is leaking. Cleaned the project from any reference to SQLite and everything is working fine. Once again this code block works.

```
}, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Customer Added");
            insertRealm.close();
        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable error) {
            Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());
            insertRealm.close();
        }
    });
```